# Media player significantly quieter than browser

Tags: sound, video, vlc, audio-player

Whenever I use the default video player, or VLC media player my sound is always suspiciously quiet. I have to turn it all the way up in order to hear it.

I thought this was an issue with my sound but when I play a video on youtube it is far louder, so I know it is not an issue with the system volume. I have tried the same video 2 media players and the issue persists. Has anyone encountered this before?

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this is a duplicate (I didn't find this exact issue here)

Comment: Ubuntu desktop 20.04 lts, sorry I am new to this. The default player is just called "video"

Comment: Did you try adjust settings in `System Volume` `Over-Amplification`?

Comment: Just my personal long time experience. It is the way it works. When I stream from HTPC I need the volume on sound system to be almost full. When using Chromecast about half volume and web sites it varies.